# Using Classic CKEditor5 with Form Control react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, ckeditor5

Hello Guys I'm very new in web developing and I want to try implementing rich text editor (I'm Using Classic CKEditor 5) with Form Control from react-bootstrap but When I wrap it with the Form.Control it not appear and showing error in the console

I Try this but it shows error

```
<Form.Control>
        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data={value}
          onReady={(editor) => {
            // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
            console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            console.log({ event, editor, data });
            onChangeText(data);
          }}
          onBlur={(event, editor) => {
            console.log('Blur.', editor);
          }}
          onFocus={(event, editor) => {
            setShowErr(true);
          }}
        />
      </Form.Control>
```

This was my alternative I use border color but it not pleasant (but working) it showing color when invalid

```
<div className={`${showErr && isInvalid ? 'container' : ''} `}>
        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data={value}
          onReady={(editor) => {
            // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
            console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();
            onChangeText(data);
          }}
          onBlur={(event, editor) => {
            console.log('Blur.', editor);
          }}
          onFocus={(event, editor) => {
            setShowErr(true);
          }}
        />
      </div>
```

I expect when I type nothing in ckeditor it will show error with react bootstrap form. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem (with React Quill) and tried this solution, for validation issues:

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Label>Evolução / Queixas</Form.Label>
    <ReactQuill theme='snow' value={evolution} onChange={setEvolution} modules={quillModules}/>
    <Form.Control type='text' isValid={isFormValidated && !Boolean(errors.evolution?.message)} style={{display: 'none'}}/>
    <Form.Control.Feedback type='invalid'>{errors.evolution?.message}</Form.Control.Feedback>
</Form.Group>
```

What I did in the code was using a "ghost" auxiliar Form.Control, invisible. In its isValid function i'm checking wether the react quill input (not the form control) is valid or not. I'm also using React Hook Form to control the input and the error messages but i don't believe it makes any difference for the sake of this solution.